# SAS calculating percentages of multiple variables

Tags: sas

I like to calculate percentages of multiple variables. That is calculting sum of each variable(column) and divide each variable sum by frequnecy. I tried to get proc summary to get those two stats and make array to compute percentages but the result values do not seem to be right but no errors in the log. I saw proc sql can do percentage calculation but I do not know how to do that for multiple variables. --must not be difficult but I just am not sure how to list them.

If you can either point out what I did wrong 1) in the proc summary way, or 2) direct me how to write proc SQL variable list, that would be great. thank you,

Here is code I wrote:

1)

```
proc summary data=m3resp;
 var Lma1-Lma69;
 output out=sumofLma sum=sumLma1-sumLma69;
run;

data sumLmaout;
 set sumoflma;
 array pctma[69];
 do i=1 to 69;
  pctma[i]=input(cat(sumLma,i),5.)/_freq_;
 end;
 drop i;
run;
```

2)

```
PROC SQL;
 SELECT Lma1
 (Lma1/SUM(Lma1)) AS PCTLma1
 FROM m3resp;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

[PROC Means](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/240-29.pdf) is a great tool for summarizing numeric variables. (To prevent the report, add NOPRINT on the PROC MEANS line).

```
data numbers;
 input num1 num2;
 datalines;
 10 5
 10 5
 10 5
 10 5
 10 5
 10 5
 10 5
 10 5
 10 5
 10 5
;

proc means n sum mean median data=work.numbers maxdec=2; 
 var num1 num2;
 output out=work.totals(drop=_freq_ _type_) 
  sum(num1 num2)=NUM1_TOTAL NUM2_TOTAL
  n(num1 num2)=NUM1_COUNT NUM2_COUNT;
run;
```

Comment: ok. you got sum and ncount for eaach variable. Thne how would you compute percentage of each variable?

Comment: I tried to use proc means for thse variables to computer percentages since these variables are 0/1 data, it works in this way. thank you!